# how can i get mysql results with alphabetical pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

how can i get mysql results with alphabetical pagination
i.e
i have 2 fields i.e id and name in mysql table and following html links for pagination

A B C D E F G .......

by clicking on A i want to get results names starting with A

how can i do that with php

Comment: Numerous duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+pagination

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280230/searching-for-advanced-php-mysql-pagination-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SQL `LIKE` syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name LIKE 'A%'
```

Comment: That query wouldn't return results that start with A, but those that end with A. so: SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name LIKE 'A%'

Comment: Yes I saw it but I hitted 'Add comment' before seeing it

Answer (score 1):

Use a query like

```
SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE :index
```

Then, bind `:index` to something like `sprintf('%s%%', $selectedIndex)`

It would also be a good idea to create an index on the `name` column.